# Appropriate workflow to create shortest path data from known start end points using Python?

Tags: python

I’d like to ask a basic question about creating shortest path data between 20 pairs of known points in Python, with a finished dataset that suitable for use in GIS with OSM.

In .csv format, I’ve four vectors – start long, start lat, end long, end lat. There is more data, but for the purpose of this task, I’ve separated out just those vectors. The coordinates fit a WGS 84 pseudo mercator projection.

Could someone give me a ultra fast breakdown of workflow as well as list the corresponding libraries to be concerned with to complete this in Python?

Perhaps, something along the lines of “reshape start points into tabular format, separate x and y coordinate in distinct vectors using x command structure from x library. Then use x function from x library to build list of nodes between start and end coordinates that when spatially constructed in GIS on OSM, is the shortest path for each trip..

In time, I’m looking to scale this up to about 150,000 trips. I feel comfortable completing this in R, or experimenting with a pyscrip in ArcGIS (not sure about scalability). However, I’m coming to terms with the spatial power of python and therefore would like to get a handle on the language for future use.. Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by shortest path? The [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)? Or are you just looking for shortest path between A and B in spherical coordinates? And then B and C and so on...

Comment: I mean the shortest path between A and B in spherical coordinates. No need for multiple stops as in the TSP.

Comment: I understand there are a number of algorithms for this operation - dijkstra is quite popular

Comment: OK, now, what would you want as the result? The distance? A list of points on the way? How many points? Points in spherical coordinates? Points in the projection? What is it for? Drawing the paths or something else?

Comment: I'd like to aggragate the trips into a heat map, quatify that heatmap, extract the most popular routes and perform some regression against related data.

Comment: For the results, I a list of points, ideally each node (so varying number of points per trips). Points in WGS 84 pseudo mercator projection.

Comment: I would take a look at [LatLon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/LatLon), [utm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/utm) and [geopy](https://github.com/geopy/geopy) libraries. Also, see [this answer from gis.stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91742/looking-for-python-module-to-do-lat-lon-calculations). BTW, you can't get "each node". The path is actually a straight line from A to B with infinite number of points on it.

Comment: Great thank you, I assume the points would be geocoordinates. Is that true?